# Why does print argument flush default to False?

Tags: python, output-buffering

I am using print to log the execution of my python scripts.

I use `flush = True` everywhere because otherwise the print statements sometimes do not occur where they were placed.

I was wondering why the default is `flush = False`. Can anyone explain?

Thanks!

Comment: Oops, I didn't sleep enough. I mixed up True and False in the question (the title was correct). Thanks!

Comment: @alex See https://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html (ignore the Perl specific parts (and some of them are a bit outdated now), but the general concept applies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By not forcing the `flush` by default, you leave that decision to the underlying object you're writing to. For `sys.stdin` / `stderr` this would default to line buffered `_io.TextIOWrapper` which is usually what you would expect and want on an interactive console. When you swap your output for a file, the default of not forcing a `flush` with each print/write seems reasonable. Conversely, forcing `flush` after each print overrides buffering/flushing behavior of the underlying object.

The obvious caveat being when you for instance run your script through `tee`, process' own `stdout` isn't writing directly to the terminal.

---

I've poked around a bit more to see if there is any textual evidence regarding the motivation. Adding `flush` keyword is documented in [issue 13761](https://bugs.python.org/issue13761). Apparently suggestion to default to `True` for `stdout` was made back in 2012, and dismissed (see towards the bottom of the discussion). I guess this is where one could apply The Zen of Python: *"Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."* (No speacial treatment just because we're writing to `sys.stdout`. ;)

There is also a [link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2012-January/013340.html) into the mailing list where BDFL himself states:

> I would be fine with adding a new keyword argument to print() in
>   3.3 to force a flush, as long as it defaults to off.